# AWK - print output

Tags: awk, grep

I have a data table in tsv format, the content of the file looks like the following.

```
    Gene_stable_ID  Gene_stable_ID_version  Transcript_stable_ID    Transcript_stable_ID_version    Gene_name   Gene_type
ENSMUSG00000064372  ENSMUSG00000064372.1    ENSMUST00000082423  ENSMUST00000082423.1    Cyp Mt_tRNA
ENSMUSG00000064371  ENSMUSG00000064371.1    ENSMUST00000082422  ENSMUST00000082422.1    mt-Tt   unprocessed_pseudogene
ENSMUSG00000064370  ENSMUSG00000064370.1    ENSMUST00000082421  ENSMUST00000082421.1    Cyp processed_pseudogene
ENSMUSG00000064369  ENSMUSG00000064369.1    ENSMUST00000082420  ENSMUST00000082420.1    Cyp pseudogene
```

My goal here is to get the rows where the 'Gene name' is 'Cyp' and 'Gene type' is 'protein_coding' or 'pseudogene' or 'processed_pseudogene' or 'processed_pseudogene'.

I used awk command to do this, like this.

```
grep -i Cyp mapping.tsv | awk -F "\t" '{ if($NF == "protein_coding" || $NF == "pseudogene" || $NF == "processed_pseudogene") { print }}'
```

Here, I only get the 'Gene name' - Cyp and 'Gene type' - protein_coding, the 'pseudogene' part is ignored.

Can you help me figure this out?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show where are tabs and where are spaces in the input?

Comment: it is a tab-delimited file, so all columns are separated by '\t'

Comment: you might be interested in searching for *bioawk*, a library based on awk and tailor-made for this kind of applications

Comment: When I replaced `s/  */\t/g` it printed the lines with protein_coding and pseudogene, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '$(NF-1)~/Cyp[0-9]+/ && ($NF=="protein_coding" || $NF=="pseudogene" || $NF=="processed_pseudogene" || $NF=="processed_pseudogene"){print $(NF-1),$NF}' Input_file
```

OR a non-one liner form of above:

```
awk '
$(NF-1)~/Cyp[0-9]+/ && ($NF=="protein_coding" || $NF=="pseudogene" || $NF=="processed_pseudogene" || $NF=="processed_pseudogene"){
  print $(NF-1),$NF
}'  Input_file
```

Considering that your fields `Gene_name` or `Gene_type` don't have spaces in their names here. Also to print complete line remove `{print $(NF-1),$NF}` part in above codes.

***EDIT:*** In case you want to use regex to check condition use following(again regex needs to be modified as per your samples too):

```
awk '
$(NF-1)~/Cyp[0-9]+/ && ($NF=="protein_coding" || $NF~/.*pseudogene/ || $NF=="processed_pseudogene"){
  print $(NF-1),$NF
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: I used grep here, because it is not only 'Cyp', it can also be 'Cyp1A1' or 'cyp2A1'

Comment: @User, check now, looks like your Samples were not having `Cyp1A1` so changed condition accordingly now, lemme know.

Comment: my bad, newbie problems, however, thanks, it works perfect now.

Comment: Hi, is there also a way to use regex here in 'if condition' than having to mention 'pseudogene' || 'processed_pseudogene' like '.*pseudogene'?

Comment: @User, Please check EDIT solution once and lemme know then.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer but as per your condition I think only grep is sufficient.

try:

```
cat mapping.tsv |grep "Cyp"|grep -E "protein_coding|pseudogene|processed_pseudogene"
```